# How to default format response when statusCode is 200 or another successful one in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

How to format the response when I got  successful response?

For example my code is

```js
 @Get(':id')
  async getOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const model = await this.categoriesService.getById(id);
    if (model) {
      return model;
    } else {
      throw new NotFoundException('Category not found');
    }
  }
```

I got a response is:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "image": null
}
```

How to default format to?

`{ status: 200|201..., data: [MyData] }`

Comment: Is there a reason why you want the status explicitly within the model? Whatever client you're making the request from should give you the status code as part of its request/response interface

Comment: No I just want to handle errors and responses. For ex default response of erorr is 
```{statusCode: 404, message: "...", error: "Not Found"}``` I want format it to ```{status: 404, message: "anyErrorMessage" ?? "Not Found"}```

P.S. This is a first day when I'm learn nestJS =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways for this response but in my opinion, is best practice is to use an `interceptor`
based on [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors)

```
// src/common/interceptors/format-response.interceptor.ts

import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor, HttpStatus  } from '@nestjs/common';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class FormatResponseInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map(value => {
        value = (value) ? value : []
        return { status: "success", data: [value]};
      }));
  }
}
```

and in the controller inject the interceptor

```
import { UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';

@UseInterceptors(FormatResponseInterceptor)
export class UserController {
    constructor() {}

 @Get(':id')
  async getOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    const model = await this.categoriesService.getById(id);
    if (model) {
      return model;
    } else {
      throw new NotFoundException('Category not found');
    }
  }
}
```

And for change the format of error, you can use [Filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters)

Answer (score 0):

I usually just explicitly write

```
try {
    ....

    return { status: HttpStatus.OK, data: [MyData] }
} catch(e){
    return { status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, message: e.message || 'my error' } 
}
```